# Design of prestressed beams and bridge decks

Tags: bridges, prestressed-concrete

When we are designing bridge decks and beams for class 1 or 2 (i.e. uncracked) we have to check both the compressive stresses (in Eurocode design we use the characteristic value of $f_{ck}$ i.e. 0.45 or 0.65$f_{ck}$ depending on whether we are designing at transfer or service) whereas to limit the tension (class 2) we use the mean value of $f_{ctm}$.

What is the reason that we don't use the characteristic value of tensile strength?

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to take the time factor into account in evaluating the strength of the concrete at the time of transfer.

[image]

**Note:**

Per EC2 Table for "Strength Classes for Concrete", $f_{ctk}$ is a function of $f_{ctm}$:

$f_{ctk;0.05} = 0.7xf_{ctm}$, 5% fractile

$f_{ctk;0.95} = 1.3xf_{ctm}$, 95% fractile

The reason for using $f_{ctm}$ rather than $f_{ctd}$ (design tensile strength of concrete) for prestressed concrete is because the development of tensile strength with time is strongly influenced by curing and drying conditions as well as by the dimensions of the structural members.

Reference: See EC2 3.1.2 (9), 3.16 & Table 3.1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I appreciate it. However the question refers to both transfer stage and serviceability stage as fctm is used for checking stresses both at transfer and serviceability. Why fctm and not fctk?

Comment: The characteristic value of tensile strength of concrete (f_ctk) is higher than the design tensile strength of concrete (f_ctd), how could it be used for checking?

Answer (score 0):

> (i.e. uncracked)

I haven't dealt with Eurocodes in a while but my eye twitched a bit at this. In practice, it is extremely difficult (aka almost nearly impossible) to get concrete to span across distances as long as prestressed beams and bridges do with absolutely no cracking. I'm not across the specific requirements of class 1 and 2 members, but I would put in an educated guess that these classes will limit cracking to a certain maximum value which is almost invisible to the naked eye (e.g. max crack widths of 0.2mm) rather than say no cracking.

Okay, rant over. Onto your main query then...

There are three concepts at play here. I'll caveat all of them by stating that these are educated guesses based on my experience so you'll want to verify them against academic sources.
I'm also assuming that when you refer to *fctk*, you're really referring to *fctk* at 5% fractile (i.e. 95% confidence)

1. Tension in concrete is almost always designed to be taken up by steel (or at
   least be backed by steel under service - see minimum reinforcement requirements). So when concrete cracks,
   steel is there to take tension. There is no such fail-safe for
   compressive failures though. If concrete fails in compresion,
   something's gone terribly wrong. This inherently implies that the
   material strengths for concrete compression need to be more
   conservative than for tension.
2. From memory, *fctm* is a more easily test-derived value than *fctk*. This is because there's way more variability in concrete tensile results than compression results - which stems from the makeup and microstructure of concrete mixes.
3. For serviceability, we accept that we cannot fully eliminate tensile cracking in concrete. Depending on the specific requirements however, we can limit cracking to certain extents by providing reinforcement. While we could form equations using *fctk*, since it's much harder to get this value than *fctm*, we use the latter instead of the former.